# Beamer in arabic language doesn't accept footnotes

Tags: beamer, footnotes, polyglossia, arabic

Using beamer in arabic language, we adapt many of its commands and themes to this language, but when I put a footnote if the arabic language is charged, I have the error message 
'! LaTeX Error: No counter 'Hfootnote' defined.'
So my question is: "How I can type footnotes in this environments?

I give a minimal example. I obtain the error message when I uncomment the line of the arabic language

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

%% to use arabic language and arabic fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
%\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.0]{Traditional Arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.0]{Tahoma}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic]{Simplified Arabic}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text\footnote{with footnote.} 
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Thanks to Karlkoehler, who give the solution for the usual footnotes, in english environments, so in LTR mode. But what about the RightToLeft mode, the arabic for example, where we define other kinds of footnotes, in LTR and RTL modes. I give an example of these footnotes:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={hyperfootnotes=false},10pt]{beamer}

%% to use arabic language and arabic fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.0]{Traditional Arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.0]{Tahoma}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic]{Simplified Arabic}

\makeatletter
\let\@footnotetext=\beamer@framefootnotetext
\makeatother

\def\efootnote#1{\leftfootnoterule\LTRfootnote{\LR{#1}}\stepcounter{footnote}}
\def\efootnotetext#1#2{\LRfootnoterule\LTRfootnotetext[#1]{\hspace*{2pt}\LR{#2}}\hspace*{-12pt}}

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% MANYFOOT FOOTNOTES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage[para*]{manyfoot}    
%%%%%%%%%%%% ARABIC RTL
\newfootnote[para]{B}
\newcounter{footnoteB}
\newcommand{\footnoteB}{%
\stepcounter{footnoteB}%
\Footnotemark\thefootnoteB
\FootnotetextB\thefootnoteB}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteB}{\hspace*{2pt}\fnsymbol{footnote}}
 \def\HِAfootnotetext#1#2{\FootnotetextB{#1}{\hspace*{2pt}\LR{#2.}}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%  ENGLISH LTR
\SetFootnoteHook{\setLTR}
\DeclareNewFootnote[para]{C}
\makeatletter
\let\c@footnoteC\c@footnote
\makeatother
\let\Hfootnote\footnoteC
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteC}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\def\Hfootnotemark#1{\footnotemarkC[#1] \stepcounter{footnote}}
\def\Hfootnotetext#1#2{\footnotetextC[#1]{\hspace*{2pt}\LR{#2.}}\stepcounter{footnote}}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%    END MANYFOOT FOOTNOTES %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
A usual footnote\footnote{footnote} 

A efootnote\efootnote{efootnote}

A footnoteB\footnoteB{footnoteB}

A footnoteC\footnoteC{footnoteC}

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

The compilation of this file doesn't stop, it number the footnotes but it writes only the first footnote

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This is a solution.

The option `hyperfootnotes` is the culprit of this behavior. So, when loading `beamer`, pass the option `hyperfootnotes=false` to hyperref, in this way:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={hyperfootnotes=false},10pt]{beamer}
```

At this point, however, footnotes won't be printed... To avoid that, we need to add the following lines in the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\let\@footnotetext=\beamer@framefootnotetext
\makeatother
```

Now it should works properly.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[hyperref={hyperfootnotes=false},10pt]{beamer}

%% to use arabic language and arabic fonts
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[calendar=gregorian,numerals=maghrib]{arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfont[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.0]{Traditional Arabic}
\newfontfamily\arabicfontsf[Script=Arabic]{Amiri}
\newfontfamily\arabicfonttt[Script=Arabic, Scale=1.0]{Tahoma}
\setsansfont[Script=Arabic]{Simplified Arabic}

\makeatletter
\let\@footnotetext=\beamer@framefootnotetext
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
Some text\footnote{with footnote.}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It works good... for the usual footnotes (in english environments and in left to right way) But what about the general footnotes, in RTL modes and so ? I give the problematic in my updated question

Comment: @FaouziBellalouna For `\efootnote` add `\let\@LTRfootnotetext=\beamer@framefootnotetext`. For the others, I don't know.

Comment: @karlkoller ok thanks. I'll try your solution. Thanks

Comment: Many thanks. Folllowing worked for me: `\makeatletter \let\@footnotetext=\beamer@framefootnotetext \makeatother`